# Как найти два соседних числовых значения в бинарном дереве поиска?

Tags: алгоритм, поиск, структуры-данных

Хочу понять самый простой способ решить задачу.
Есть значения на числовой прямой и нужно по запросу найти пару существующих соседних значений для входящего числового значения. Дубликатов точек быть не может, как в структуре так и на входе.

Пример: в дереве 1, 5, 6, 7.56, 100 и на входе 8, то результат (7.56, 100)

Или тут лучше подходит другая структура данных? (Необходима максимальная скорость)

UPD:
На словах придумал, но реализацию еще нет.
Назовем искомое значение v. Начинаем искать v. Если последнее значение меньше v(нода1), то **необходимо найти ноду с минимальным значением которое будет больше ноды1** (нода2). Если последнее значение больше v(нода2), то **необходимо найти ноду с максимальным значением которое будет меньше ноды2** (нода1). Если в дереве найдена нода со значением v, то сообщаем об исключении. Если какого-то значения из пары нет, то заменить его на null в ответе, к примеру (null,null) или (3,null).

Comment: эти значения на числовой прямой статичные? Или обновляются? Если обновляются, то как часто?

Comment: Если вы хотите найти элементы, соседние с заданным, чем вам обычный сортированный массив не угодил?

Comment: Могут быть вставки и удаления. Да, наверно сортированный массив тут лучше всего подходит. Спасибо!

Comment: на массиве промахов кэша, по идее, больше

Comment: Вставка/удаление в сортированный массив займет линейное время. Если у вас есть вставки/удаления, то тогда дерево будет лучше.

Comment: Дубликаты в исходных данных имеются?

Comment: "Дубликаты в исходных данных имеются?" - нет

Comment: Что если заданное число для поиска меньше/больше всех чисел в дереве? То есть только минимум или максимум из дерева ближайшие?

Comment: Тогда выдать (null,1) или (100, null), на тех данных что в примере

Comment: если половинным делением искать в большом массиве, то первые несколько делений возможны обращения к новым страницам памяти. С B-деревом, у которого один узел влезает в страницу памяти, и в одном узле много ссылок на детей, сначала  будет поиск внутри массива детей, а только потом -- к новому узлу; в общем, пробовать надо.

Comment: В общем, с вашими исходными данными, вам походу надо сбалансированное дерево поиска применять, если вы хотите максимальной эффективности. Обычное бинарное дерево поиска вам не подойдет, так как вам надо менять данные.

Comment: Автор пока не ответил, будут ли данные меняться.

Comment: Ещё вопрос - сколько данных то вообще и как часто к ним идёт обращение? Если данных очень много, я бы в SQL таблицу записал, сделал индекс по этому полю - и пусть база думает.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте на данных реального для вашей задачи  размера тривиальный отсортированный массив и бинарный поиск.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, B+-дерево будет лучше просто бинарного дерева, исходя из использования кэша процессора. И возможно, даже лучше бинарного поиска в большом массиве.

Куча (heap) расположена в линейном/виртуальном адресном пространстве.
Физически данные могут находиться в кэше процессора (доступно очень быстро), оперативной памяти (нормально), выгружены в своп (медленно).

При обращении к виртуальному адресу данные переносятся большими кусками (страница памяти (см. TLB) и блок кэша (cache-line)) из медленных подсистем в быстрые.

Т. е. если обратиться по адресу, который соответствует выгруженной странице, то это будет очень долгой операцией. Зато последующее обращение к соседним адресам будет очень быстрым.

Если половинным делением искать в большом массиве, то первые несколько делений возможны обращения к новым участкам памяти. С B+-деревом, у которого один узел влезает в единицу кэширования, и в одном узле **много** ссылок на детей, сначала будет поиск внутри массива детей, а только потом -- к новому узлу;

В листьях дерева -- сортированные массивы.

---

Критика реализации векторов в scala, не про поиск, а вообще:

> ... cache-locality, where the 32-way branching ... faster than working with binary trees ...

https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html#vectors-are-ok

Вывод: вектор лучше просто деревьев, но во многом хуже просто массива.
Т. е. если данных не много, то массив лучше всего, даже с учетом копирования при вставке.

---

В абстрактах пары статей (не вчитывался) говорится:

Effect of Node Size on the Performance of Cache-Conscious B+-trees:

> in modern processors, the over-all performance  of an index structure depends  on the number  of cache  misses,  the  instructions  that  are  executed,  the  number  of mispredicted conditional branches, and the number of TLB misses.

[http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jignesh/publ/cci.pdf](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ejignesh/publ/cci.pdf)

Making B+-Trees Cache Conscious in Main Memory:

> Cache Sensitive SearchTrees  (CSS-Trees)  perform  lookups  much **faster  than binary search**

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.444.6716&rep=rep1&type=pdf

---

А возможно, есть и какая-то совсем специализированная структура.

В общем, пробовать надо.

Comment: А можно ссылку на "...использования кэша процессора", "... первые несколько делений возможны обращения к новым страницам памяти"? Не очень понимаю как это работает. К примеру делаю реализацию на c# и знаю что есть кучи и стек.

Comment: развернул объяснения и ссылки

Comment: В самом деле, CSB+ деревья выглядят симпатично. Как вы правильно заметили, пробовать надо, подбирать  оптимальный размер узлов индекса и данных и метод поиска (последовательный (не стоит забывать о cache lines prefetch) или бинарный) в узлах

Answer (score 0):

### 1-й способ

Сбалансированное бинарное дерево поиска.

Предположим, Вы знаете как найти в дереве элемент с конкретными значением.

Пусть `X` - узел дерева, который содержит найденное "входящее числовое значение".

Что же до поиска предшественника, то эта задача несильно сложнее:

- если у найденного элемента есть левое поддерево, то предшественник является его максимальным элементом; другими словами, берём левого сына и в цикле проходим по иерархии узлов вниз, на каждом уровне выбирая правого сына, пока не упрёмся в листовой узел:

```cpp
t = X->Left_Child;
while ( t->Right_Child != null )
{
    t = t->Right_Child;
}
return t->Value;
```

- в противном случае (т.е. левое поддерево пустое) поднимаемся по иерархии вверх, пока не найдётся узел с ключом меньшим, чем значение X:

```cpp
t = X->Parent;
while ( t->Value > X->Value )
{
    t = t->Parent;
}
return t->Value;
```

Асимптотика алгоритма:

- построение дерева из `n` входных элементов: `O(n*log(n))`
- поиск X: `O(log(n))`
- поиск предшественника: `O(log(n))`

Суммируем, меньшие оценки поглощаем большими, и получаем итоговую оценку:

`O(n*log(n))`

### 2-й способ

Бинарный поиск по отсортированному массиву.

Пусть `A` - отсортированный массив, где храним входные данные.

Пусть `X` - "входящее числовое значение", для которого нужно определить значение предшествующее.

Пусть `i` - это индекс "входящего числового значения", найденный бинарным поиском.

Тогда `(i-1)` будет индексом предшественника, а значение предшественника - `A[i-1]`.

Асимптотика алгоритма:

- сортировка на основе сравнений: `O(n*log(n))`
- бинарный поиск: `O(log(n))`
- вычисление предшественника: `O(1)`

Суммируем, меньшие оценки поглощаем большими, и получаем итоговую оценку:

`O(n*log(n))`

### Оптимизация

Можно ли достичь лучшего по скорости?

Да, можно! Только есть ограничения:

- входные данные должны быть в относительно узком диапазоне значений, например числа от 1 до 10000
- данные должны быть распределены относительно равномерно по оси между минимальным и максимальным значениями
- во **2-м способе** сортировку на основе сравнения заменяем - будем использовать сортировку на основе значений ключей (примеры: [сортировка подсчётом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC) и [корзинная сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)) с линейной асимптотикой `O(n)`

В этом случае асимптотика алгоритма "поджимается":

- сортировка на основе значений: `O(n)`
- бинарный поиск: `O(log(n))`
- вычисление предшественника: `O(1)`

Суммируем, меньшие оценки поглощаем большими, и получаем итоговую оценку:

`O(n)`

### 3-й способ

Можно ли добиться ещё более быстрого результата?

И да и нет :)

"Нет" - потому, что не можем опуститься ниже оценки `O(n)` - т.к. нужно прочитать входные данные целиком.

"Да" - потому, что в оценке `O(n)` можем уменьшить скрытый константный множитель!

Как это сделать? Ну, раз мы уже упомянули **корзинную сортировку**, давайте попробуем проэксплуатировать её основную идею в своих целях.

Итак, корзинная сортировка делит числовую ось на интервалы, и для каждого интервала создаёт "корзину", в которой складываются все значения, попадающие на этот интервал. Если набор корзин реализовать массивом списков, а размер каждой корзины задать константой `c`, то сортировка становится до неприличия простой:

```cpp
A = new int[n];  // входные данные
B = new List<int>[max(A)/c];  // набор корзин

// 1-й проход - читаем входные данные
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    B[A[i]/c].add(A[i]);
    
// 2-й проход - сортируем внутренности каждой корзины
for (i = 0; i < max(A)/c; i++)
    B[i].sort();

// 3-й проход (необязательный) - переписываем числа из набора корзин обратно в линейный массив A[]
```

А теперь подумаем - нужно ли нам сортировать сразу **все** корзины?

Правильный ответ - "конечно, нет!" :)

Составляем итоговый план алгоритма:

- раскладываем числа по корзинам
- определяем корзину, где лежит искомое число `X`; это просто - значение `X` делим на значение `c` (размер корзины); пусть индекс корзины с числом `X` равен `i`
- сортируем `i`-ю корзину (при константном размере корзины её сортировка любым алгоритмом принимается за `O(1)`!)
- бинарным (или даже линейным) поиском определяем в корзине позицию числа `X`; пусть его индекс внутри корзины будет `j` (поиск внутри корзины в любом случае будет быстрее сортировки этой корзины, так что асимптотику тоже принимаем за `O(1)`!)
- если `j > 0`, то в качестве ответа возвращаем значение корзины с индексом `(j-1)` и завершаем выполнение
- (если `j = 0`) идём влево от `i`-й корзины, пока не найдём *непустую*; ищем в непустой корзине максимальный по значению элемент и возвращаем его в качестве ответа (и опять, по тем же соображениям, асимптотика этого шага принимается за `O(1)`!)

Асимптотика алгоритма:

- раскладывание по корзинам: `O(n)`
- определение корзины с элементом `X`: `O(1)`
- сортировка корзины с элементом `X`: `O(1)`
- поиск ближайшей слева непустой корзины: `O(n)`  (в худшем случае проверим на [пусто/непусто] **все** корзины, число которых линейно)
- вычисление максимального элемента корзины: `O(1)`

Суммируем, меньшие оценки поглощаем большими, и получаем итоговую оценку:

`O(n)`

P.S.:

Вообще-то, оценка асимптотической сложности для алгоритмов подсчётной и корзинной сортировки не совсем `O(n)`, а скорее `O(r)`, где `r` - диапазон значений входных данных, т.е. `r = max(A) - min(A)`. Но во многих случаях (зависящих от входных данных) можно считать оценки `O(n)` и `O(r)` эквивалентными.

Кроме того, оценки `O(n)` для "оптимизированного" 2-го способа (равно, как и для 3-го) являются оптимистичными, для усреднённого случая. Однако, возможны и худшие случаи входных данных , когда алгоритм будет отрабатывать за время похуже линейного.

Впрочем, это бывает и с некоторыми известными алгоритмами - так, неаккуратно реализованный QuickSort может деградировать с `O(n*log(n))` до `O(n^2)` при особых входных данных.